# puting variables of an array in a row of another array in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

as i said in topic name, i want to put variables of 3 arrays in a row of another array.
look: for example i have 3 arrays X1, X2, X3 that them variables are:

```
X1=[1 2 3];   
X2=[4 5 6];   
X3=[7 8 9];
```

and another array Y is this look:

```
Y=zeros(3,3);   
0  0  0   
0  0  0   
0  0  0
```

now i want randomize X1 in first row, X2 in second row and X3 in third row like this:

```
3  1  2   
4  6  5   
9  8  7
```

many thanx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easier to do if your `Xi` row vectors are in a single array `X`.

**EDIT**: Thanks to LuisMendo for the optimization suggestion.

```
X = [X1;X2;X3];
[rows,cols] = size(X);
Y = zeros(rows,cols);

for i = 1:rows
    Y(i,randperm(cols)) = X(i,:);
end
```

Comment: It would be interesting to know which is faster: `Y(i,:) = x(randperm(size(X,2)))` or `Y(i,randperm(size(X,2))) = x`

Comment: @LuisMendo Nice thinking. That's probably the faster method.

Comment: i have another question.
X1=[1 2 3]; ==> the hour of start of exam
X2=[1...n]; ===> the day start program
X3=[1..n]; ===> these are courses code
for  each number in X2(day) we should have each number of X1.
X1   1  2  3  1  2  3 ...
X2   1  1  1  2  2  3 ...
X3    no matter
have i spoke clearly? :-s

Comment: @SajadKhammar In other words, you want to pick one element from `X1`, one element from `X2`, and one element from `X3`, and find all possible combinations?

Comment: @eigenchris   at first, i chose your coding because when i have expanded my arrays its was ok.
*************

i am trying to build a simple coding for examination program planning.   i have hour and day and course code.   all of these show with digits.   for example hour '1' is 8am to 10am or hour '2' is 11 am to 13pm and hour '3' may be 15pm to 17pm .   and days are 1 to n (holding range).   and third  is courses code no matter witch one.    eg. Math is '1' ...   now i want build a program that one course do not start in a day and also in same day. wish you got my bad English :( :'( :s

Comment: @eigenchris I didn't mean to imply that indexing on the left-hand side is faster than on the right-hand side. I was only suggesting that one of the options may be faster than the other, but I'm not sure which one. In other words: I'm not sure whether your edit is really an _optimization_ :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo The suggestion you made does seem to be mildly faster based on some tests I did. More time was saved by combining the two lines in my loop into one, however.

Comment: @eigenchris do you got my question?

Comment: @eigenchris Oh, so you tested both; got it. And yes, that intermediate `x` seemed unnecessary. Maybe also change `i` into some other name, to [avoid shadowing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab)?

Comment: @LuisMendo yes, it appears that in general indexing on the left increases the speed of assignment by a marginal amount, though I am not sure why. Maybe because indexing on the right creates a whole new object in memory that must then be assigned? I'm not sure how MATLAB handles this at a low level. As for the `i` issue, I tend to use the `1i` solution when I need the imaginary unit, and freely use `i` and `j` as loop variables, though that's just my personal preference.

Comment: @SajadKhammar So you want to find all combinations of hours, days, and course codes, so that courses do not repeat themselves in the same day?

Comment: @SajadKhammar That's a significant change to your original question. Maybe post a new one?

Comment: @LuisMendo please check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30095855/examation-program-planning-using-matlab

Comment: @eigenchris please check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30095855/examation-program-planning-using-matlab

Comment: @LuisMendo im waiting for your help friend

Answer (score 1):

Use [`randperm`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html):

```
n = size(Y,2); %// number of columns
Y(1, randperm(n)) = X1;
Y(2, randperm(n)) = X2;
Y(3, randperm(n)) = X3;
```

Comment: it is correct thanx. im amateur in Matlab please explain 'size(Y,2)'  and also randperm.

Comment: `size(Y,2)` is the number of columns of `Y` (more info about `size` function [here](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html)). `randperm(n)` is a random permutation of the numbers `1`, `2` , ..., `n`. See the [link in my answer](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html) for more details about `randperm`.

Comment: i have another question.
X1=[1 2 3]; ==> the hour of start of exam
X2=[1...n]; ===> the day start program
X3=[1..n]; ===> these are courses code
for  each number in X2(day) we should have each number of X1.
X1   1  2  3  1  2  3 ...
X2   1  1  1  2  2  3 ...
X3    no matter
have i spoke clearly? :-s